# How to display a graph in ipython notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Trying to do some plotting in SymPy -

As per [this video](https://youtu.be/cvHyaE_bs8s?t=1028) I have written :

```
from sympy.plotting import plot, plot_parametric

e = sin(2*sin(x**3))
plot(e, (x, 0, 5));
```

But after evaling that cell I don't get any output? There isn't an error or
anything, it just doesn't display anything.

Another test :

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot, plot_parametric
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


expr = x**2 + sqrt(3)*x - Rational(1, 3)
lf = lambdify(x, expr)

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

x_vals = np.linspace(-5., 5.)
y_vals = lf(x_vals)

axes.grid()
axes.plot(x_vals, y_vals)

plt.show();
```

So Im not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm not getting any errors though?

If the virtual environment content is of any interest here's a tree of that :
[venv](https://bpaste.net/show/0bcb2c219d7e)

I'm running this on Linux Ubuntu. The virtual environment that it's running in can be seen in the above paste link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [magic functions](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions), more specifically the ones for [matplotlib](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib):

```
%matplotlib qt # displays a pop-up of the plot
%matplotlib inline # keeps it within the notebook
```

Runnable example using Python 3.4 Nov '15:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot, plot_parametric
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

expr = x**2 + sqrt(3)*x - Rational(1, 3)
lf = lambdify(x, expr)

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

x_vals = np.linspace(-5., 5.)
y_vals = lf(x_vals)

axes.grid()
axes.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
```

Comment: this is correct thanks, I didn't notice this on the guide that I was following but this now works

Answer (score 4):

To get plots to show inline in the IPython notebook, you need to enable matplotlib's inline backend. You can do this by running

```
%matplotlib inline
```