# Is there any way to properly format docs in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've just discovered that `function?`, like `len?` will bring up documentation for that function in ipython.

One library has `.. math::` blocks and `.. plot::` in its docs.

The former seems to need to be passed to a latex engine and the latter to a python interpreter to plot a graph which is embedded in the docs. Sadly, in my jupyter notebooks client, I just get the code for these.

Is there any way to have this code be executed by both latex and python so that I may get the intended output?

NB: A sample output
`pm.Exponential?`

```
The pdf of this distribution is

.. math::

   f(x \mid \lambda) = \lambda \exp\left\{ -\lambda x \right\}

.. plot::

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.stats as st
    plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
    x = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
    for lam in [0.5, 1., 2.]:
        pdf = st.expon.pdf(x, scale=1.0/lam)
        plt.plot(x, pdf, label=r'$\lambda$ = {}'.format(lam))
    plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('f(x)', fontsize=12)
    plt.legend(loc=1)
    plt.show()

========  ============================
Support   :math:`x \in [0, \infty)`
Mean      :math:`\dfrac{1}{\lambda}`
Variance  :math:`\dfrac{1}{\lambda^2}`
========  ============================

Parameters
----------
lam: float
    Rate or inverse scale (lam > 0)
File:           ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/continuous.py
Type:           type
Subclasses:
```

Comment: These directives are used by [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.0/ext/math.html) to compile docs from the source code. They are not expected to be properly rendered in function signature.

Comment: If you're looking to document your code in a notebook, Google Colabs have great support for this- even including LaTeX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a graph in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855699/how-to-display-a-graph-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: @Marat do you have a quick cli command I can use to take that source from stdin and compile it to a pdf? I'm looking to make myself a helper in my bashrc that will compile the sphinx source

Comment: @Edward I'd expect this to be a non-trivial task. Compiling sphinx docs often relies on having specific versions of dependencies and non-trivial hacks. It's probably easier to write a helper to find links to already compiled documentation rather than compile it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/) + fastbook gives me what I want.

The following snippet gives the intended result.

```
!pip install torch nbdev fastbook
import fastbook
fastbook.setup_book()
```